# problema con formdata y enviar un ID adicional

Tags: javascript, ajax, formdata, vanilla

tengo un problema, envió mis datos por formdata y ps llega todo bien pero ahora el detalle es que necesito enviar un ID adicional y no lo quiero incluir en el formulario dentro del formdata,  eso se podrá hacer de alguna forma? coloco aquí mi código, obviamente cuando quito mi id todo se envía bien pero quiero ver como lo envió por post sin tener que quitar el formdata  ya que también estoy subiendo imágenes.

```
function guardar_logo_emp(){
    

    let form = document.querySelector('form[name="valid_logo"]');   
    form.append(data_per_ad, Dat_per_ad_consult);
     let fd = new FormData(form);

    

     let A = document.getElementById('guardar_logo_emp');
     let B = document.getElementById('loadingTodos');
     let ajax = xmlhttp();
                var url = 'guardar_logo_emp.php';
        
    let button = document.querySelector(".button_submit");
        button.classList.add("disabled");
    
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
            
                    
                if(ajax.readyState==1){
                      B.innerHTML = "";
                        A.innerHTML = loading;
                    }
                if(ajax.readyState==4){
                    
                        A.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                        B.innerHTML = "";
                    
let cam_anim = document.querySelector("#guardar_logo_emp");
let Animar_now = cam_anim.classList.contains("animation_act");                  
    
            if (Animar_now==true){

    cam_anim.classList.remove("animation_act");
    cam_anim.classList.add("animation_off"); 
    
        setTimeout(reanimar,2000);
        
    function reanimar(){    
                
    button.classList.remove("disabled");            
                
    cam_anim.classList.remove("animation_off");
    cam_anim.classList.add("animation_act");
    }
        
    }                   
                
window.scrollTo(0,550); 

                }
            } 

             ajax.open("POST", url);
        ajax.send(fd);      
}
```

acabo de ver que con append se podria pero no logro hacerlo

CODIGO EDITADO CON EL PROBLEMA YA SOLUCIONADO

Comment: No incluyas la respuesta que te han dado en la pregunta. Léete de nuevo y más detenidamente [tour] para entender mejor la dinámica del sitio y aprende a aceptar las respuestas que te han dado y te han servido para que tu colaboración en este sitio sea la correcta y esperada.  En tu perfil veo que ya has realizado muchas preguntas y ninguna respuesta aceptada, y seguramente más de una si que merece ser aceptada. No hacerlo también influye en las ayudas posteriores que te puedan dar en nuevas preguntas.

Comment: En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas, gracias por tu colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar el campo al objeto `FormData` y no al formulario:

```
let form = document.querySelector('form[name="valid_logo"]');   
let fd = new FormData(form);
// Agregar a objeto FormData, el nombre entre comillas
fd.append('data_per_ad', Dat_per_ad_consult);
```

Si todavía te da error, revisa la consola del navegador, probablemente se trate de cómo obtienes el valor para `Dat_per_ad_consult` o en qué momento lo defines.